# Simplifying expression with complex exponentials and sinusoids to just sinusoids

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I can't get Mathematica to simplify this as I expect it would/should:

```
tst = Simplify[
ComplexExpand[(A* s*(s^2*L1 C1 + 1))/((s^2 + ω^2) (s^2*L1 C1 + s R1 C1 + 1))]]

j=I;

values={
  R1 -> 180,
  C1 -> 9.4*10^-9, 
  L1 -> 0.0017
 };

InverseLaplaceTransform[tst, s, t] /. values/. A -> 3 /. ω -> 2*π*138 k // Simplify
```

this returns:

> (0.0261497 + 0.0522889 I) E^((-52941.2 - 244490. I) t) + .0261497 - 0.0522889 I) E^((-52941.2 + 244490. I) t) + 2.9477 Cos[276000 π t] - .392636 Sin[276000 π t]

I've tried `ExptoTrig`, then `TrigReduce`, but nothing seems to get me there.

I can see (I think) that as a minimum, the `Sin` term from the addition of the complex exponentials should cancel, and I would expect to be able to get the final answer in the form of

$A*cos(wt+\Phi)$

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: It seems that you are dealing with a transfer function of a RLC circuit. However, should not `tst` be a complex function?...

Comment: Maybe: `In[2160]:= Chop[
 ExpandAll[(0.0261497 + 
       0.0522889 I) E^((-52941.2 - 244490. I) t) + (.0261497 - 
       0.0522889 I) E^((-52941.2 + 244490. I) t) + 
    2.9477 Cos[276000 \[Pi] t] - .392636 Sin[276000 \[Pi] t] /. 
   Exp[cc_Complex*t] :> Exp[Re[cc]*t]*ExpToTrig[Exp[Im[cc]*I*t]]]]

Out[2160]= 
0.0522994 E^(-52941.2 t) Cos[244490. t] + 
 2.9477 Cos[276000 \[Pi] t] + 
 0.1045778 E^(-52941.2 t) Sin[244490. t] - 
 0.392636 Sin[276000 \[Pi] t]`

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, indeed, but I should be able to express it in terms of sinusoids via Eulers....The A∗cos(wt+Φ) implies complex...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau --> I don't understand your comment.  what is cc_Complex and cc? how does it work?  Thank you.

Comment: Its a basic pattern match substitution.